# Laravel Controller Request Verify

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Can someone help me verify a request via controller? I don't know how to do this.

```
public function verify(Request $request){
    
        $key = clean($request->purchasecode);

        $response = \Core\Http::url("https://cdn.gempixel.com/validator/";)
                            ->with('X-Authorization', 'TOKEN '.md5(url()))
                            ->body(['url' => url(), 'key' => $key])
                            ->post()
                            ->getBody();

        if(!$response || empty($response) || $response == "Failed"){
            
            return back()->with("danger", "This purchase code is not valid. It is either for another item or has been disabled."); 

        }elseif($response == "TooMany"){

            return back()->with("danger", "This purchase code is already used on another domain. If you need to reset it, please us your purchase code and domain to reset it.");

        }elseif($response == "Wrong.Item"){

            return back()->with("danger", "This purchase code is for another item. Please use a Premium URL Shortener extended license purchase code.");

        }elseif($response == "Wrong.License"){

            return back()->with("danger", "This purchase code is for a standard license. Please use a Premium URL Shortener extended license purchase code.");

        } else {
        
            $setting = DB::settings()->where('config', 'purchasecode')->first();
            $setting->var = $key;
            $setting->save();

            $this->seelfdb($response);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Seelfdb:code
     *
     * @author GemPixel <https://gempixel.com> 
     * @version 6.0
     * @return void
     */
    private function seelfdb($r){

        $q = str_replace("_PRE_", DBprefix, $r);
        $qs = explode("|", $q);

        foreach ($qs as $query) {
          if(!DB::raw_execute($query)){
            return Gem::trigger(500, 'Task failed.');
          }
        }
        
        return back()->with('success', base64_decode('RXh0ZW5kZWQgdmVyc2lvbiBoYXMgYmVlbiBzdWNjZXNzZnVsbHkgdW5sb2NrZWQuIFlvdSBtYXkgbm93IHVzZSBwYXltZW50IG1vZHVsZXMgYW5kIHN1YnNjcmlwdGlvbnMu'));
    }
}
```

It's a laravel based website. I need to enable payment methods, the only method to do this is by verifying the purchase code. You can see the validator URL in the code. But I want to Bypass or something like this to verify any purchase code to trigger

```
$setting = DB::settings()->where('config', 'purchasecode')->first();
           $setting->var = $key;
           $setting->save();

           $this->seelfdb($response);
```

And then I couldn't understand what is this code

```
private function seelfdb($r){

       $q = str_replace("_PRE_", DBprefix, $r);
       $qs = explode("|", $q);

       foreach ($qs as $query) {
         if(!DB::raw_execute($query)){
           return Gem::trigger(500, 'Task failed.');
         }
       }

       return back()->with('success', base64_decode('RXh0ZW5kZWQgdmVyc2lvbiBoYXMgYmVlbiBzdWNjZXNzZnVsbHkgdW5sb2NrZWQuIFlvdSBtYXkgbm93IHVzZSBwYXltZW50IG1vZHVsZXMgYW5kIHN1YnNjcmlwdGlvbnMu'));
   }
```

Comment: This code makes no sense to me. What are you trying to do? What are you trying to verify? What is a purchase code? What service are you using and for what purpose?

Comment: It's a laravel based website. I need to enable payment methods, the only method to do this is by verifying the purchase code. You can see the validator URL in the code. But I want to Bypass or something like this to verify any purchase code to trigger
`$setting = DB::settings()->where('config', 'purchasecode')->first();
            $setting->var = $key;
            $setting->save();

            $this->seelfdb($response);`

And then I couldn't understand what is this code
`foreach ($qs as $query) {
   if(!DB::raw_execute($query)){
           return Gem::trigger(500, 'Task failed.');`